# Mathematical Induction Can't get past base step... Please help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The Question:
For all integers $n ≥ 1$ prove $1+2^1 +2^2 +\dots+2^n = 2^{n+1} −1$.

I am having a hard time with this. when I let $n=1$, my base step is false. What do I do now?

Comment: $1+2^1=3=2^{(1+1)}-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the base step is false, the proof fails as a whole.
However, for the base step $n=1$, we actually find 
$$ 1+2^1 = 3$$
for the left hand side and
$$ 2^{1+1}-1=4-1=3 $$
as well, so the base step is fine.

Comment: So it's 1+2^1=2^(1+1)-1. I thought that it was 2^n=2^(n+1)-1 (with n=1). No wonder why I was coming up false. Thanks Everyone :)